# Hover is triggered when mouse over child element

Tags: css

I am trying to use transition effects on a drop down menu and using `display: none` stops the transition from happening so instead I am using opacity.

A strange thing is happening.  When the mouse hovers over the see-through sub menu it becomes visible but I have selected this behaviour to happen when mousing over parent `<li>` and I am not mousing over it.  The child '` is absolutely positioned below it.

In the snippet below, move your mouse underneath `post` and the sub menu will appear.  I only want it to appear when the mouse is ontop of the post box in the black border.

There is something going on here I don't understand.

```css
menu-main-menu-container {
  position: relative;
}

ul.menu {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.menu > li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
  top: 100%;
}
ul.menu li.menu-item-has-children:hover > ul.sub-menu {
  opacity: 1;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
ul.sub-menu li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-2385" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-2385 menu-item-depth-0"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2386" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2386 menu-item-depth-0"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/get-quote-inner/">testimonials</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2387" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2387 menu-item-depth-0"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/services-inner/">Login</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2388" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-2388 menu-item-depth-0"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/blog-post-8/">post</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-2646" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2646 menu-item-depth-1"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2647" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2647 menu-item-depth-1"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/services/">Services</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2390" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2390 menu-item-depth-2"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/product/this-is-a-product/">product</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2649" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2649 menu-item-depth-2"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/login/">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2648" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2648 menu-item-depth-1"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/contactus/">Contactus</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2389" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2389 menu-item-depth-0"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/service-fence-inner/">page</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2391" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2391 menu-item-depth-0"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/expert/gagan-goraya/">expert</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I inspect the `<li>` it is not resizing over the child absolutely positioned `<ul>` so why is it triggering the `li:hover` effect?

Comment: You are using `opacity` to hide the element. The problem with opacity is that the element is actual still there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the opacity will only change the actual visibility to you, the user.

The browser and the DOM will both render the element anyway. The space of the element is used, it's just not visible to you.

An easy fix would be setting a `max-height` to 0 and changing it to something you're never going to reach on hover. This way, the space it will usually take is limited to 0. Also regulating your overflows will help.

```css
menu-main-menu-container {
  position: relative;
}

ul.menu {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.menu > li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
  top: 100%;
}
ul.menu li.menu-item-has-children:hover > ul.sub-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 1000px;
  overflow: visible;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  max-height: 1000px;
}
ul.sub-menu li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-2385" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-2385 menu-item-depth-0"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2386" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2386 menu-item-depth-0"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/get-quote-inner/">testimonials</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2387" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2387 menu-item-depth-0"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/services-inner/">Login</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2388" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-2388 menu-item-depth-0"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/blog-post-8/">post</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-2646" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2646 menu-item-depth-1"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2647" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2647 menu-item-depth-1"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/services/">Services</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2390" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2390 menu-item-depth-2"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/product/this-is-a-product/">product</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2649" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2649 menu-item-depth-2"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/login/">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2648" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2648 menu-item-depth-1"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/contactus/">Contactus</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2389" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2389 menu-item-depth-0"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/service-fence-inner/">page</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2391" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2391 menu-item-depth-0"><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/expert/gagan-goraya/">expert</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is this a normal approach or should I be coming at this differently?

Comment: In most situations the display property is used, but as you mentioned, this prevents the transition from happening. This is a pretty common fix for that so no need to worry about if this is good enough.

Comment: I've tried what you said but its not working for some reason

Comment: I'm sorry, i just made an edit, forgot to add the overflow property!

Comment: nested menu under services isn't working I think it's due to how I have positioned it using relative size :S

Comment: Made a second edit. Where I added the `overflow:hidden` on the `<ul>`, I added `overflow:visible` on the hover now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93097/discussion-between-steyn-van-esveld-and-guerrilla).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

See the child ul with the class sub-menu is a part of li with the class menu-item-has-children so if you hover beneath the li it will consider as li got hovered.

```
ul.menu > li.menu-item-has-children a:hover + ul.sub-menu {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: problem is that you then cannot go to select a link because it will dissapear again